# R - package marmap - read.bathy - depth values NA

Tags: r

I'm using RStudio and the package Marmap to import my 3 columns txt file (latitude, longitude and depth values).

[image: lat long depth]

After the import all the depth values appear as NA.

[image]

I've tried different file format (csv) but the result was the same.

Can someone help me. 
Thanks,

Paulo

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `plot(praia)`? It seems you have an enormous amount of `NA`s, but you also have a few (726!) non missing values.

Since the data you're trying to import are obviously not regularly spaced, you should check `?griddify()`